# Google rejecting emails

Tags: smtp, sendmail, gmail

Google is rejecting emails and send me

```
<<< 550-5.7.1 [XXXX:XX:XX:XX::63] Our system has detected that this message does
<<< 550-5.7.1 not meet IPv6 sending guidelines regarding PTR records and
<<< 550-5.7.1 authentication. Please review
<<< 550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=IPv6AuthError for more 
information
<<< 550 5.7.1 . u185si7215567ioe.331 - gsmtp
554 5.0.0 Service unavailable
```

A PTR record does exit for both IP's as well as an A record for what is shown in the PTR record. I have done this in the past with no issue. Only thing I can think of is there is a subdomain for the box (foo.nyc.example.org). Is there any of troubleshooting to see what snedmail sends out in the headers to Google?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the v6 address and FQDN to /etc/aliases seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

IPv6 PTR record must match IPv6 address.